# Negative unconditional variance forecast for EGARCH model in R

Tags: r, time-series, garch, volatility-forecasting

I'm trying to model several financial time series and to get some forecast on them.
Considering the log-returns, I fitted an EGARCH(1,1) on the data and got the parameters, as known constraint-free because of the model:
$$
\text{log}(\sigma^2_t)=\omega + \alpha_1 g(\eta_{t-i}) + \beta \text{log}(\sigma^2_{t-j})
$$
which considers exponentation for the parameters.

So I fit the model with `ugarchfit` function from `rugarch` package in R and then I use the `ugarchforecast` function to get the unconditional volatility of series. In the output I can notice many negative prediction!

Is that a problem of model-validity or does the `ugarchforecast` function return the conditional log-volatility so I have to exponentiate my output?

Comment: What does the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf) or the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) say about that?